# Can this python function be vectorized?

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, numpy, vectorization

I have been working on this function that generates some parameters I need for a simulation code I am developing and have hit a wall with enhancing its performance.

Profiling the code shows that this is the main bottleneck so any enhancements I can make to it however minor would be great.

I wanted to try to vectorize parts of this function but I am not sure if it is possible.

The main challenge is that the parameters that get stored in my array `params` depends upon the indices of params. The only straightforward solution to this I saw was using `np.ndenumerate`, but this seems to be pretty slow.

Is it possible to vectorize this type of operation where the values stored in the array depend upon where they are being stored? Or would it be smarter/faster to create a generator that would just give me the tuples of the array indices?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import linalg as LA

def get_params(num_bonds, energies):
    """
    Returns the interaction parameters of different pairs of atoms.

    Parameters
    ----------
    num_bonds : ndarray, shape = (M, 20)
        Sparse array containing the number of nearest neighbor bonds for 
        different pairs of atoms (denoted by their column) and next-
        nearest neighbor bonds. Columns 0-9 contain nearest neighbors, 
        10-19 contain next-nearest neighbors

    energies : ndarray, shape = (M, )
        Energy vector corresponding to each atomic system stored in each 
        row of num_bonds.
    """

    # -- Compute the bond energies
    x = LA.lsqr(num_bonds, energies, show=False)[0]

    params = np.zeros([4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4])

    nn = {(0,0): x[0], (1,1): x[1], (2,2): x[2], (3,3): x[3], (0,1): x[4],
          (1,0): x[4], (0,2): x[5], (2,0): x[5], (0,3): x[6], (3,0): x[6],
          (1,2): x[7], (2,1): x[7], (1,3): x[8], (3,1): x[8], (2,3): x[9],
          (3,2): x[9]}

    nnn = {(0,0): x[10], (1,1): x[11], (2,2): x[12], (3,3): x[13], (0,1): x[14],
           (1,0): x[14], (0,2): x[15], (2,0): x[15], (0,3): x[16], (3,0): x[16],
           (1,2): x[17], (2,1): x[17], (1,3): x[18], (3,1): x[18], (2,3): x[19],
           (3,2): x[19]}

    """
    params contains the energy contribution of each site due to its
    local environment. The shape is given by the number of possible atom
    types and the number of sites in the lattice.
    """
    for (i,j,k,l,m,jj,kk,ll,mm), val in np.ndenumerate(params):

        params[i,j,k,l,m,jj,kk,ll,mm] = nn[(i,j)] + nn[(i,k)] + nn[(i,l)] + \
                                        nn[(i,m)] + nnn[(i,jj)] + \
                                        nnn[(i,kk)] + nnn[(i,ll)] + nnn[(i,mm)]

return np.ascontiguousarray(params)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach using [`broadcasted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) summations -

```
# Gather the elements sorted by the keys in (row,col) order of a dense 
# 2D array for both nn and nnn
sidx0 = np.ravel_multi_index(np.array(nn.keys()).T,(4,4)).argsort()
a0 = np.array(nn.values())[sidx0].reshape(4,4)

sidx1 = np.ravel_multi_index(np.array(nnn.keys()).T,(4,4)).argsort()
a1 = np.array(nnn.values())[sidx1].reshape(4,4)

# Perform the summations keep the first axis aligned for nn and nnn parts
parte0 = a0[:,:,None,None,None] + a0[:,None,:,None,None] + \
     a0[:,None,None,:,None] + a0[:,None,None,None,:]

parte1 = a1[:,:,None,None,None] + a1[:,None,:,None,None] + \
     a1[:,None,None,:,None] + a1[:,None,None,None,:]    

# Finally add up sums from nn and nnn for final output    
out = parte0[...,None,None,None,None] + parte1[:,None,None,None,None]
```

**Runtime test**

Function defintions -

```
def vectorized_approach(nn,nnn):
    sidx0 = np.ravel_multi_index(np.array(nn.keys()).T,(4,4)).argsort()
    a0 = np.array(nn.values())[sidx0].reshape(4,4)    
    sidx1 = np.ravel_multi_index(np.array(nnn.keys()).T,(4,4)).argsort()
    a1 = np.array(nnn.values())[sidx1].reshape(4,4)
    parte0 = a0[:,:,None,None,None] + a0[:,None,:,None,None] + \
         a0[:,None,None,:,None] + a0[:,None,None,None,:]    
    parte1 = a1[:,:,None,None,None] + a1[:,None,:,None,None] + \
         a1[:,None,None,:,None] + a1[:,None,None,None,:]
    return parte0[...,None,None,None,None] + parte1[:,None,None,None,None]

def original_approach(nn,nnn):
    params = np.zeros([4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4])
    for (i,j,k,l,m,jj,kk,ll,mm), val in np.ndenumerate(params):    
        params[i,j,k,l,m,jj,kk,ll,mm] = nn[(i,j)] + nn[(i,k)] + nn[(i,l)] + \
                                        nn[(i,m)] + nnn[(i,jj)] + \
                                        nnn[(i,kk)] + nnn[(i,ll)] + nnn[(i,mm)]
    return params
```

Setup inputs -

```
# Setup inputs
x = np.random.rand(30)
nn = {(0,0): x[0], (1,1): x[1], (2,2): x[2], (3,3): x[3], (0,1): x[4],
      (1,0): x[4], (0,2): x[5], (2,0): x[5], (0,3): x[6], (3,0): x[6],
      (1,2): x[7], (2,1): x[7], (1,3): x[8], (3,1): x[8], (2,3): x[9],
      (3,2): x[9]}

nnn = {(0,0): x[10], (1,1): x[11], (2,2): x[12], (3,3): x[13], (0,1): x[14],
       (1,0): x[14], (0,2): x[15], (2,0): x[15], (0,3): x[16], (3,0): x[16],
       (1,2): x[17], (2,1): x[17], (1,3): x[18], (3,1): x[18], (2,3): x[19],
       (3,2): x[19]}
```

Timings -

```
In [98]: np.allclose(original_approach(nn,nnn),vectorized_approach(nn,nnn))
Out[98]: True

In [99]: %timeit original_approach(nn,nnn)
1 loops, best of 3: 884 ms per loop

In [100]: %timeit vectorized_approach(nn,nnn)
1000 loops, best of 3: 708 µs per loop
```

Welcome to **`1000x+`** speedup!

---

For a system of generic number of such *outer* products, here's a generic solution that iterates through those dimensions -

```
m,n = a0.shape # size of output array along each axis
N = 4  # Order of system
out = a0.copy()
for i in range(1,N):
    out = out[...,None] + a0.reshape((m,)+(1,)*i+(n,))

for i in range(N):
    out = out[...,None] + a1.reshape((m,)+(1,)*(i+n)+(n,))
```

Comment: This is really excellent! I have never come across this kind of design pattern before, thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @Steve It's been fun! Look into `NumPy broadcasting` for more info and look for more usages of it on SO if you are really interested! :)

Comment: I've used `NumPy broadcasting` in the past, but only for simpler cases. This is really great though, I am still learning how to vectorize more complicated functions.

Comment: I have been revisiting your approach and I have a couple of questions.  Namely, under the step "Perform the summations keep the first axis aligned for nn and nnn parts", how did you determine that you needed to only add three extra dimensions here?  I would like to add more components to the params array, i.e., an "nnnn" or even an "nnnnn".  How can I scale this?

Comment: @Steve Check out the added section at the end. Edit the `N` there to `5`, `6` and so on for `nnnn`, `nnnnn`, etc.

Comment: How did you learn to take advantage of broadcasting so well? Are there any references you could point me towards?

Comment: @Steve Just keep practicing on avoiding loops! :)